# Cannot fill missing values with new pivot_wider() from tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I am getting crazy with the new `tidyr::pivot_wider()` function with the missing values feature.
It works sometimes, sometimes not.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
require('tidyr')
df <- data.frame(
  color = c("green", "yellow"),
  nb = c(1758, 12)
  )

# add one level
df$color <- factor(df$color, levels = c("green", "yellow", "red"))
```

This works well:

```r
# with deprecated `spread`
spread(data = df, 
       key = color, value = nb, 
       fill = 0,
       drop = F)
```

```
>>  green yellow red  
>>1  1758     12   0
```

But this does not

```r
# with new `pivot_wider`
pivot_wider(data = df, 
            names_from = color, 
            values_from = nb, 
            values_fill = list(nb = 0))
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  green yellow
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1758     12
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I have noted this [partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327101/pivot-wider-does-not-seem-to-work-with-missing-values-how-to-turn-spread-into) but I would like to get an equivalent behaviour of my function, not having to add an intermediate step.

Comment: That's just not possible in `pivot_wider` at this time. (Of course, you can add the 0 to the data.frame before `pivot_wider` for the desired result). There's a [feature request](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/770) for it on GitHub so hopefully the functionality will be added later.

Comment: That is correct. I made a confusion between the "drop" and "fill missing" topics, they are related to each other but not identical indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete` to create the combination bassed on the `levels` and then use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  complete(color = levels(color), fill = list(nb = 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = color, values_from = nb)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  green   red yellow
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  1758     0     12
```

Comment: In fact, your approach with `complete` is exactly what I needed.  I used to get the expected result by using successively `spread(..., drop = F)` and `gather()` but this was unelegant. This makes me saves those steps. Thank you !